# Save injected code

Tags: debugging, injection, memory-dump

I am analyzing a binary that is injecting code into another process (i.e., svchost.exe) to make the debugging more tedious. I can attach the new process to a debugger (e.g., ollydbg or the one featured by IDA Pro) and read the assembly code. However, I was wondering whether it is possible or not to take like a snapshot of this so I can later on analyze the code offline (as any other binary).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your definition of a "snapshot" is somewhat vague. Hopefully my answer matches your idea:

Did you already take a look at the [OllyDumpEx Plugin](http://low-priority.appspot.com/ollydumpex/)?

> This plugin is process memory dumper for OllyDbg and Immunity
>   Debugger. Very simple overview: OllyDumpEx = OllyDump + PE Dumper -
>   obsoleted + useful features

Of course you can simply dump the raw memory as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341726/how-to-dump-memory-into-raw-file-in-ollydbg) with 
`ollydbg` itself.